# How can a callback parameter passed to a function be aware of that function's own return value?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, return

Sorry if there's already other question around this subject. I couldn't find one.

Could somebody elaborate on how this code works?

I wasn't expecting the `result` from `foo()` to be available inside the `callback` declaration that is being passed as a parameter of `foo`.

What is the order of events that happens in a situation like this?

It's like the function returns first and only then it creates its own parameter? How does that make sense?

```js
const foo = (callback) => {
  setTimeout(callback,500);
  return 42;
};

const result = foo(() => {
  console.log('From callback...');
  console.log('result:',result); 
})
```

Similar to this:

```js
const id = setTimeout(() => console.log('id',id),500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `foo` runs, which sets the callback to be run after 500ms, and then returns with 42. That gets stored in the `result` variable.

After 500ms the callback from `foo`'s parameter gets called, and finds the variable `result` as a global variable and prints it out (which is set to be 42)